# Zend server on Windows not loading php_ibm_db2.dll

Tags: php, windows, db2, zend-server

I've spent my day trying to make my Zend Server on localhost (Windows 8) reading a DB2 file on a i5 system.

I've followed a lot of guides and read answers to similar questions and now:

- I have ibm express-C installed on my machine
- I have php_ibm_db2.dll in ext\ folder
- application.ini has extension=php_ibm_db2.dll pointing at the right folder
- my environment variable path has [...]C:\Program Files\ibm\gsk8\lib64;C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\gsk8\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\FUNCTION;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\SAMPLES\REPL;

But restarting the server, in the logs, i find "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\lib\phpext\php_ibm_db2.dll'"

Even if it's the right path to the dll.

And the server doesn't recognise db2_connect() (undefined)

Any idea of what's going on?
Is it possible that Windows 8 64bit is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the DLL is compiled for an incompatible version of PHP. You can grab an alternate build of the extension here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/db2mc/files/IBM_DB2%20PHP%20Driver%20for%20Windows/

I'm not seeing a build for PHP 5.5. This may mean you won't be able to get it to work with PHP 5.5 without compiling it yourself.

For PHP 5.4, note the difference between ts (threadsafe) and nts (non-threadsafe) installations of PHP.

For older PHP releases, make sure to grab something built with a compatible compiler. You probably want VC9 (Visual C++ 9), as that corresponds to the [official PHP download](http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.3).

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your reply.

The php version running is 5.4.21 on Zend Server Version: 6.2.0 with thread safety disabled.
php -m returns me ibm_db2 but the warning at server loading continues and Technology Explorer for IBM v4.2 confirms:
"PHP database driver check: IBM_DB2 PHP module was not found".
Think I'm giving up... :(

Comment: Is it still broken with this .dll? http://sourceforge.net/projects/db2mc/files/IBM_DB2%20PHP%20Driver%20for%20Windows/PHP%205.4._/php_ibm_db2-1.9.5-5.4-nts-vc9-x86.zip/download

Comment: Nothing to do, is the one I'm currently using (or trying to...)

Must I put php_ibm_db2.pdb somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

What is the extension_dir pointing to in application.ini. Looks like you have specified extension= and extension_dir too is having some value. Hence the 2 paths could be getting appended, leading to the error

Could you check for the above if the case is so and give a try by correcting to have the path in extension_dir and just the module name (php_ibm_db2.dll) in extension.

Thanks

Praveen

Comment: Hi, I found extension_dir and extension declarations are in php.ini not in application.ini (my fault).
Anyway they seem to be correct:

extension_dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\lib\phpext"
extension=php_ibm_db2.dll

and I confirm that C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\lib\phpext\php_ibm_db2.dll is the right path.

Thank you for you reply

Comment: Hi 

The next thing I would check for given that php -m loads the dll properly (lets call it standalone)...is your PATH settings recognised by zend (Apache)...if the respective PATH setting is not visible to Apache then chances are that the dll would not be found and hence the error. 
<br>
Hint: might have to check httpd.conf

Comment: I checked and found that typing php -m, under [PHP Modules] appears ibm_db2, but still not working (and not loaded by the server).
If I try to connect first thing I see is a Notice: 
"Notice: Use of undefined constant DB2_AUTOCOMMIT_ON - assumed 'DB2_AUTOCOMMIT_ON' in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\data\libraries\Zend_Framework_1\1.12.3\library\Zend\Db.php on line 270"

Maybe it helps...
Thank you for your reply!